# Random last modified timestamps on an NFS file

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-efs

While creating an application I encountered a strange behaviour. When reading file last modified timestamp I sometimes received random values. I came up with a theory about it, so I decided to perform an experiment.

I ran two threads on ubuntu @ AWS EC2 server.

- The first thread periodically (with random delays) creates and
  deletes a file.
- The second thread periodically (with random delays)
  checks the file last modified timestamp.

Kotlin code:

```
fun main() {
    Thread(::createAndDelete).start()
    Thread(::measure).start()
}

fun createAndDelete() {
    println("starting createAndDelete thread")
    var i = 0
    while(true) {
        try {
            Files.createFile(Paths.get("$workingDirectory/test"))
        } catch (e: FileAlreadyExistsException) {

        }
        Thread.sleep(nextLong(10, 30)) // A random delay
        try {
            Files.delete(Paths.get("$workingDirectory/test"))
        } catch (e: NoSuchFileException) {

        }
        if(++i % 100 == 0)
            println("created and deleted $i times")
    }
}

fun measure() {
    println("starting measure thread")
    var i = 0
    while(true) {
        try {
            val time = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get("$workingDirectory/test")).toMillis()
            if(!Files.exists(Paths.get("$workingDirectory/test")))
                continue
            val time2 = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get("$workingDirectory/test")).toMillis()
            if(time != time2)
                continue

            val difference = abs(Date().time - time)
            if (difference > 10000) { // This happens a lot when using AWS EFS
                println("time = $time, difference = $difference")
            }
        } catch (e: NoSuchFileException) {

        }
        Thread.sleep(nextLong(10, 20)) // A random delay
        if(++i % 100 == 0)
            println("measured $i times")
    }
}
```

The results are normal as long as I use local storage.
However, when I use a mounted external NFS (AWS EFS) volume, I sometimes get file last modified timestamps of random values. Even with the precaution of measuring twice the timestamp and checking for the file existence in the middle.

```
starting createAndDelete thread
starting measure thread
time = 747720714000, difference = 817721554205
time = 1167151114000, difference = 398291154309
time = 1485918218000, difference = 79524050386
time = 1636913162000, difference = 71470893579
time = 1771130890000, difference = 205688621545
time = 177360906000, difference = 1388081362585
time = 294801418000, difference = 1270640850615
time = 445796362000, difference = 1119645906648
time = 1217548298000, difference = 347893971133
measured 100 times
```

What is the exact reason for this behaviour?

Is there any way to make the last modified timestamp reading reliable?

Comment: You might want to see if you can duplicate this behavior with the `stat` command line utility.  Also, does the value drift if you just monitor it, without actually modifying the file?

Comment: In the target solution, I'd rather not call other applications whenever I want to check this statistic (which happens a lot). The value changes because the file is being constantly recreated.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. The point isn't to change how your code works.  The point is that general troubleshooting principles suggest that you need to seek other sources of truth to see of they support or refute your tentative conclusion that the mtimes are actually as bizarre as they appear. Most of the mtimes you are getting are not just a little bit wrong -- they are complete nonsense.  What if the mtimes aren't actually wrong, but there's something broken in the language/library you are using or the way you are using it?  You need to confirm or refute that.  Try a test with `stat`.

Comment: Need more details about the server, and NFS protocol version, nfs client version (i.e. kernel version), and mount options.